# RMI: RMI Reaper thread, UnicastRemoteObject and Registry

Tags: java, rmi

I have problem with RMI Reaper thread which doesn't allow all my program to terminate as this thread is not daemon. I found information that this thread stops only when all objects are unexported. So I have the following code to create rmi serer.

```
registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2525);
Server stub = (Server) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(defaultServer, 2525);
registry.rebind("//localhost/server", stub);
```

And I have two versions of "unexporting".
Version 1:

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(defaultServer, true);
```

Version 2:

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry, true);
```

When I use version 2 - RMI Reaper thread doesn't terminate and all the program doesn't terminate. When I use version 1 everything ok. However, in many places I found the following code:

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(rmiRegistry, true); // Stop the RMI registry
```

Could anyone explain why and how Registry is linked with UnicastRemoteObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2525);
```

That exports a Registry.

```
Server stub = (Server) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(defaultServer, 2525);
```

That exports your remote object `defaultServer`.

*Ergo*, when unexporting, you have to use both the lines you mentioned:

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(defaultServer, true);
```

unexports your own remote object, and

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry, true);
```

unexports the Registry that you started.

> how Registry is linked with UnicastRemoteObject.

You bound your remote object into the Registry. For DGC purposes that makes the Registry a client of your remote object, which keeps it alive.

Comment: Can I export registry via UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject?

Comment: No, because you can't construct an object of the required class and give it the required RMI object ID.

Comment: But why when I don't unexport registry I don't have problems with RMI reaper thread? Can it mean, that registry exported and unexported automatically?

Comment: It is exported by `createRegistry()`, not automatically, but it can be *unexported* automatically if your `registry` variable isn't static, so it can be locally garbage-collected.

Comment: How to check if it is static?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Can you show example of static registry? I do get registry from factory. How can it be static?

Comment: It's your `registry` variable. Only you know whether it's static. Factories have nothing to do with it whatsoever. NB It *should* be static, so it doesn't just disappear on you unexpectedly.

Comment: I understood you mean `static Registry registry;`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations. Then I would recommend to correct you answer. Because, as I understood to unexport manually registry is not always required.

Comment: My answer is already correct, and your understanding is a misunderstanding.

Comment: No thanks. I'm not much interested in your miusunderstandings. I've done my best to correct them. If you want more information see my book *java.rmi: the Guide to Remote Method Invocation,* Pitt & McNiff, Addision Wesley 2001.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help even if I find that there is some logical error in it.

Comment: OK, I'll bite, you find *what* logical error in it? Be specific.

Comment: You said: `you have to use both the lines you mentioned`. You used `have to`. So I must do it in any case. However, we found out that not in any case.

Comment: That's not a 'logical error', it is a question of fact. Strange language you're using. You have to use both the lines I mentioned unless you have also failed to make the `Registry` reference static, which will cause other problems. It's all stated here. The only *logical* error here is accepting an answer you don't believe to be correct.

Comment: Please, pay attention that I didn't say about registry reference - it is static or not. The main problem was in RMI thread. So, this is the starting point. Anyway, you spent your time to help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pavel_K I see I was extraordinarly patient with you for some reason, but don't accuse people of logical errors unless you know what you're talking about and can back it up. Next time I certainly will not be so patient.